# Why not show views in NestedScrollView on Android

Tags: android, xml, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

In my application I want show `ViewPager` into `NestedScrollView`, and I write below code.

**Show** me `TabLayout` but **not show** me `ViewPager` in `NestedScrollView` .

**My XML codes :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <app.test.Componenets.PlusTabLayout.TabLayoutPlus
                android:id="@+id/celebrityMovieFrag_tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size3"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size3"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/size3"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/allCapsTabLayout"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/darkBlueGrey" />

            <app.test.Componenets.DisableSwipeViewPager
                android:id="@+id/celebrityMovieFrag_viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/celebrityMovieFrag_tabLayout" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you put your layout in `ScrollView` or `NestedScrollView` then always use one `<LinearLayout>` and put all other layout on that. Try this code

```
<RelaytiveLayout>

   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

      <LinearLayout>
           //put your layout here
      <LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelaytiveLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code into **NestedScrollView**

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```